# Javascript Redirect Not Going To Correct URL

Tags: javascript

I have this peice of javascript:

```
<script>
var reg = "website.com";
var mob = "website.com/m";

if(window.innerWidth >= 1024) {
   if(window.location.href != reg)
      window.location.replace("http://" + reg + window.location.pathname + window.location.search)
}
else {
   if(window.location.href != mob)
      window.location.replace("http://" + mob + window.location.pathname + window.location.search)
}
</script>
```

When I run this, it keeps reloading the page - Any ideas how this can be sorted out?

Comment: `location.hostname` is the *host name* - it will never include directory parts

Comment: `window.location.hostname` is *never* going to equal `website.com/m/` -- hostnames don't contain paths.

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing `window.location.hostname` to `mob`. Have you tried logging both to see what's happening when your width is < 1024?

```
console.log(window.location.hostname); // -> website.com
console.log(mob);                      // -> website.com/m/
```

As you can see, `window.location.hostname` is **only** the hostname i.e. the bit *before* the slash.

Try a comparison based around `window.location.href` (or `window.location.pathname`) instead.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but now it does nothing! when I load the page at less than 1024 it just stays on the .com site

Comment: @user3177012 Post your new code. Also post a `console.log` of any variables you have used in your new code, so we/you can see what comparison is being made.

Comment: @user3177012 You haven't posted the `log` so we can see what values are being compared. You also, presumably, only want to compare the beginning of the `href`, not the whole thing. Do some logging and you'll see what is going on for yourself (or, if not, you'll help us to help you).

Comment: I don't know how to `log` - My console says `window.location.href is not a function`

Comment: @user3177012 If you don't know how to `console.log`, Google `how do i console.log`. We aren't your personal Googlers. Your error message is because you've written `window.location.href(...)`. `href` is not a function, so you can't pass parameters to it. You can leave that line as `window.location.replace(...)`, like you had it before.

Comment: I'm not asking anyone to Google anything. I've edited my original question as now it keeps refreshing the page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64950/discussion-between-shai-and-user3177012).

Answer (score 0):

window.location.href return url with http:// and your "reg" and "mob" not starting with http://.
Please try after adding http to varibles.